# Case statement inside trigger

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

```
create trigger Insert_emp on dbo.emp
after insert
as
begin

declare @tablename varchar(50)
declare @rdatetime varchar(20)
declare @month int

set @rdatetime = (select Bdate from inserted)
set @month = (select datepart(mm,@rdatetime))
case when @month = 2 then set @tablename = 'FEP_EMP' end
print @tablename 
end
```

Trigger will execute after,inserting record in emp table.It will pick up date which is inserted.From that date month will be calculated.I want set value of tablename.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that.I am using sql server 2005.

Comment: `CASE` in SQL Server can only return **scalar values** - not expressions or code blocks

Comment: Please be aware that `inserted` is a pseudo-table, and can contain *multiple* rows. As such, assigning a value to a scalar variable as you do is quite dangerous - it will assign a value from *one* row (which one is undefined). If you assign multiple variables in this way, each one may get assigned values from *different* rows. You ought to write you trigger to always treat `inserted` as a table with multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CASE in SQL Server can only be used to get scalar values - it **cannot** be used to decide which code block or statement to execute. To handle conditional code execution, use the regular `IF` / `ELSE` statements.

Change your trigger to something like:

```
create trigger Insert_emp on dbo.emp
after insert
as
begin

   declare @tablename varchar(50)
   declare @rdatetime varchar(20)
   declare @month int

   set @rdatetime = (select Bdate from inserted)
   set @month = (select datepart(mm,@rdatetime))

   IF @month = 2 
      set @tablename = 'FEP_EMP' 

   print @tablename 
end
```